# PRAW installation error

Tags: python, praw

I'm trying to install PRAW on windows, but I keep getting this error when i try pip install PRAW in cmd. I also can't seem to find any help online but i'm not particularly tech-savvy so I'm sorry if this is a simple question

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py"
, line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\instal
l.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py"
, line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install
.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install
.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line
 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line
 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.
py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python
36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\requests'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two theories:

1. Either cmd.exe does not have admin permissions to perform mkdir in that particular folder
2. The folder the installer is trying to modify is read-only

If running cmd.exe with admin privileges does not work, go to

```
`'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\requests'`
```

and check if it is read only. You may need admin privileges to do this as well.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click on Start button
2. Type cmd
3. Click "Run as Administrator"
4. Try installing praw again like you did before.